# Creating route for given schema according to json document

Tags: json, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I want to save data in database using following schema:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var ObjectId = Schema.ObjectId;

// Task schema
var taskSchema = mongoose.Schema({

 tasktype  : {type: String},
 createdon : {type: Date, default: Date.now},
 createdby : {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,ref: 'User'},
 visitedby : [{type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,ref: 'User'}],
 taskinfo  : [{ isactive:Boolean, taskobject:String, taskdetails:String, iscompleted:Boolean}]  

});
module.exports = mongoose.model('Task', taskSchema);
```

Here is link to json document:[Link](http://www.jsoneditoronline.org/?id=118a16030d6d3394f6dab4fdcd31b6fe)

```
[
  {
    "_id": "55f4e4f5fe8b36980a611519",
    "tasktype": "Basic",
    "__v": 0,
    "taskinfo": [
      {
        "isactive":"True" ,
        "taskobject": "paid",
        "taskdetails": "This is task one",
        "iscompleted": "False"
      },
      {
        "isactive": "False",
        "taskobject": "free",
        "taskdetails": "This is task two",
        "iscompleted": "False"
      },
      {
        "isactive": "True",
        "taskobject": "paid",
        "taskdetails": "This is task three",
        "iscompleted": "False"
      },
      {
        "isactive": "True",
        "taskobject": "free",
        "taskdetails": "This is task four",
        "iscompleted": "False"
      }
    ],
    "visitedby": [],
    "createdon": "2015-09-13T02:52:37.512Z"
  }
]
```

I want to write route (controller) in nodejs using rest api but I dont know how to save array field in mongodb using mongoose.

If you can please suggest me good resource as i have bought some udemy course but there tutor only told about fieldname: res.body.fieldname to take user input
which is not working for me in this case.

It would be great if you can tell me how can i save array in my database,

Here is sample route file which is incorrect, please help me

```
var Task     = require ('../models/task');
var User       = require ('../models/user');
var config     = require ('../../config');
module.exports = function(app, express) {

    var api = express.Router();

  api.post('/tasks', function (req, res) {
    var task = new Task({

          tasktype  : req.body.tasktype,
          taskinfo  : req.body.taskinfo,
      }); 

     task.save(function(err){
        if(err){
           res.send(err);
        return;
        }
       res.json({message:'Task has been created'})
      });
return api
}

Package.json [on request]
{
  "name": "todotask",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "test module",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "madhur",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "*",
    "express": "^4.13.3",
    "express-session": "*",
    "gulp": "^3.9.0",
    "gulp-nodemon": "^2.0.3",
    "mongoose": "*",
    "morgan": "*",
    "multer": "^1.0.3",
    "passport": "*",
    "passport-facebook": "*",
    "passport-google": "*",
    "passport-http": "*",
    "passport-local": "*",
    "passport-twitter": "*",
    "serve-favicon": "*",
    "socket.io": "*"
  }
}
```

Thank You

Comment: you can send array in req.body

Comment: it is not working abhay, someone told me you have to push

Comment: push is in mongoDB query , but in route you can simply send data in list

Comment: have you check the route i have created ?? can you tell me the edits in it ?

Comment: In which fields of Task Document you want to save Array , I will make code for you

Comment: please check taskschema there i have multiple fields which are array type 
please help me save task info.... also check json document i have posted.

Answer (score 0):

send this type of data from client site

```
taskinfo:[{
        "isactive":"True" ,
        "taskobject": "paid",
        "taskdetails": "This is task one",
        "iscompleted": "False"
      },{
        "isactive": "False",
        "taskobject": "free",
        "taskdetails": "This is task two",
        "iscompleted": "False"
      }]
```

from client site send this data using postman(google app) . If there is any error then paste that error

Comment: TypeError: object is not a function
<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at C:\projects\rt\app\routes\api.js:16:26
    <br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\projects\rt\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
unable to post full error